# Bash loop 1000x overhead over loop core

Tags: bash, for

Here is a little experiment:

```
t1=$(date +%s%N)
ta=0
for i in `seq 1 1000`
do
    t1a=$(date +%s%N)
    echo blabla
    t2a=$(date +%s%N)
    ((ta=ta+(t2a-t1a)))
done
t2=$(date +%s%N)
echo diffb: $((t2-t1))ns
echo diffba: $((t2a-t1a))ns
```

The results:

```
diffb: 2767264439ns # this is the overall result
diffba: 1482172ns # this is the aggregated result for the core
```

I can see people thinking now: this is obviously the instrumentation within the loop core. But no. I have seen this in a far more complex loop with IO operation, sort, uniq, if, cp... After a few runs, I had between 100x-1000x overhead for the whole loop!!

But, just to be sure, I swapped the `echo blabla` with `date +%s%N`. The results:

```
diffb: 3713962570ns
diffba: 2662492ns
```

It is definitely NOT the instrumentation!

Ok, then try this:

```
a=0; while [[ $((a++)) -lt 1000 ]];
```

results:

```
diffb: 3761656210ns
diffba: 1953502ns
```

---

Am I missing here something? Is there something glaringly obvious here, why these results are false? Or did I just stumbled upon reality? Bash loops have the highest overhead in the universe??

(I wanted to optimize the code, so I started to measure a baseline, but it seems, it is beyond optimization.)

EDIT: I did something else, I dropped the iteration count from 1000 to 500 (I used the while loop for this), results:

```
diffb: 1886513017ns
diffba: 2328892ns
```

compare with:

```
diffb: 3761656210ns
diffba: 1953502ns
```

It really does seem to be the loop overhead, since the core is already hitting some non-linear timing, maybe some constant initialization, or some kernel caching stuff, whatever.

Comment: `bash` is known for being comparably slow. Any heavy operations are better being done using a proper programming language.

Comment: Where are you getting this "100x-1000x overhead" from? I see a loop that takes a total time of 2767264439 ns, with the last iteration taking 1482172 ns, and 2767264439/1482172 ~ 1800 ~ which is only about 0.8x overhead per loop iteration. And on top of that, running `date`, an external, is waaaaaaaaaaaaaay more expensive than running `echo`, which is built-in. Even your `date` loop has 3713962570/2662492 ~ 1400 ~ 0.4x overhead. :/

Comment: @muru Aaaaaaaahhhhhh!!!!!! That's it!!!!!!!! I wanted to print `$ta`, not `$((t2a-t1a))`!!!!!! Put it in answer:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is in the last line.

You calculated the time of one iteration. A 1000 times slower, than 1000 iterations.